# Scrape Html Table they will provide some empty result

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/catalogo/elenco-alfabetico/400/A']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='exbox-name']/a/@href"):
            yield response.follow(link.get(),callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="expo-table general-color"]//tr')
        table = {}
        for row in rows:
            key = row.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get(default='').strip()
            value = row.xpath('.//td[2]/text() ').getall()
            value = ''.join(value).strip()
            table.update({key: value})

        yield table
```

I am trying to scrape table but they will not give the information of `Telefono`,`Fax`,`Email`,`Membro di`,`Social` check these

```
{'Indirizzo': 'Dr.-Auner-Str. 21a', 'Città': 'Raaba / Graz', 'Nazionalità': 'Austria', 'Sito web': '', 'Stand': 'Pad. 5 B22 C27', 'Telefono': '', 'Fax': '', 'E-mail': '', 'Social': ''}
```

the link of page is http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/espositore/a-mannesmann-maschinenfabrik-gmbh

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values for telephone and fax etc are in an `a` tag therefore you need to adjust your xpath selectors to account for those cases.
See below sample

```py
import scrapy

class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/catalogo/elenco-alfabetico/400/A']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='exbox-name']/a/@href"):
            yield response.follow(link.get(),callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="expo-table general-color"]/tr')
        table = {}
        for row in rows:
            key = row.xpath('./td[1]//text()').get(default='').strip()
            value = row.xpath('./td[2]/text() ').getall()
            value = ''.join(value).strip()
            if not value:
                value = row.xpath('./td[2]/a/text() ').getall()
                value = ''.join(value).strip()
            table.update({key: value})

        yield table
```